# Create namedtuple instance from string on runtime (reflection /dynamic creation)

Tags: python-3.x, reflection, runtime, namedtuple

How can I create instance of a namedtuple dynamically? is it possible?

```
Msg = collections.namedtuple('Msg', 'a b c')
...
mymsg = Msg(a=1,b=2,c=3)
msg_as_dict = mymsg._asdict()
msg_as_dict['recover_name'] = type(mymsg).__name__
```

How can I create Msg instance back from `msg['recover_name']` on runtime?

UPDATE:
How can I get the type of the namedtuple in runtime? meaning, get "Msg" from exists instance.

Comment: You know that *call by name* is a serious anti-pattern? Furthermore it is terribly unsafe to do this here since the "type" is constructed as a product of a function call.

Answer (score 6):

This will work with no reflection required:

```
def test_tuple_builder(self):
    from collections import namedtuple

    name = "Foo"
    attribs = "bar baz goo tar taz"
    values = [100, "Hello", -1, "World", "1968"]

    tpl_cls = namedtuple(name, attribs)
    foo = tpl_cls(*values)

    self.assertEqual(values[0], foo.bar)
    self.assertEqual(values[1], foo.baz)
    self.assertEqual(values[2], foo.goo)
    self.assertEqual(values[3], foo.tar)
    self.assertEqual(values[4], foo.taz)

    print("We always use '{baz}, {tar}' as an example.".format(baz=foo.baz, tar=foo.tar))
```

All tests pass and the output:

> We always use 'Hello, World' as an example.

Comment: How can you get the namedtuple name ("Foo") ?

Comment: All the parameters, including `Foo` can be passed into a function that returns a namedtuple instance. `Foo` is an arbitrary name.

Comment: I would like to pass the instance and get back it's type, when type is unknown in the first place.

Comment: `type(object)` will give the type. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: that returns `<class 'type'>`. I've updated the question.